# Using a malloc for an int array in typedef struct

Tags: c, malloc, typedef

i'm facing a problem regarding the use of malloc for an array in a typedef struct in C.
I don't know how to make the allocation dynamic in a typedef struct, the compiler does not report errors but the program opens and closes returning -1073741819.
In the program i'm reading the number of reviews of a restaurant in order to get a review average of the restaurant itself.

```
typedef struct{          
   int number_of_evaluations;
   int *evaluations;
}reviews;
reviews arr_rew[LEN];     //Where LEN=200

void charge_review(review arr_rew[LEN]){
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("recensioni.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL) {
        puts("================\nFile didn't opened\n================"); 
    }
    else
    {
        for(i=0;!feof(fp);i++)
        {
            fscanf(fp, "%d", arr_rew[i].number_of_evaluations);
            reviews* evaluations=malloc(arr_rew[i].number_of_evaluations*sizeof(int));
            for(int j=0;j<arr_rew[i].number_of_evaluations;j++)
            {
                fscanf(fp, "%d", arr_rew[i].evaluations);
            }

        fclose(fp);
        }
    }
}
```

What did i do wrong? - - Sorry for my bad english

Comment: What is `review arr_rew[LEN]` in the parameter list? You haven't defined a `review` typedef.

Comment: `fclose(fp)` should not be in the loop.

Comment: The code you show is not enough. For example you talk about "returning" and nothing in your code correspond. Show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

> What did i do wrong?

You allocated `evaluations` but wrote `arr_rew[i].evaluations` unitialised and without indexing by `j`.

Change:

```
reviews* evaluations=malloc(arr_rew[i].number_of_evaluations*sizeof(int));
```

to

```
arr_rew[i].evaluations = malloc( arr_rew[i].number_of_evaluations * sizeof(int) ) ;
```

(or better):

```
arr_rew[i].evaluations = malloc( arr_rew[i].number_of_evaluations * 
                                 sizeof(*arr_rew[i].evaluations) ) ;
```

and

```
fscanf(fp, "%d", arr_rew[i].evaluations) ;
```

to

```
fscanf( fp, "%d", arr_rew[i].evaluations[j] ) ;
```

You also close the file while you are still writing to it, and the use of `feof()` in this manner is flawed as it is only true *after* you attempt to read past the end of the file.  Instead check the file i/o operations for success and exit the loop if any fail.

```
    int input_check = 1 ;
    for( int i = 0; input_check != 0; i++ )
    {
        input_check = fscanf(fp, "%d", arr_rew[i].number_of_evaluations);

        if( input_check != 0 )
        {
            arr_rew[i].evaluations = malloc( arr_rew[i].number_of_evaluations * 
                                             sizeof(*arr_rew[i].evaluations) ) ;

            for( int j = 0; input_check != 0; j < arr_rew[i].number_of_evaluations; j++ )
            {
                input_check = fscanf( fp, "%d", arr_rew[i].evaluations[j] ) ;
            }

        }
    }
    fclose( fp ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the result of `malloc()` to `arr_rew[i].evaluations`. And then you need to index into that array when reading the evaluation values.

And `evaluations` should be `int*`, just like the `evaluations` member of the `reviews` struct.

```
void charge_review(review arr_rew[LEN]){
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("recensioni.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL) {
        puts("================\nFile didn't opened\n================"); 
    }
    else
    {
        for(i=0;;i++)
        {
            if (fscanf(fp, "%d", arr_rew[i].number_of_evaluations) != 1) {
                break;
            }
            int* evaluations=malloc(arr_rew[i].number_of_evaluations*sizeof(int));
            for(int j=0;j<arr_rew[i].number_of_evaluations;j++)
            {
                fscanf(fp, "%d", &evaluations[j]);
            }
            arr_rew[i].evaluations = evaluations;
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

Other issues:

- Don't use `!feof(fp)` as the loop condition. See [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong) for the reason. Check the result of `fscanf()` instead.
- `fclose(fp)` needs to be outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everybody, the code now finally works with the dynamic allocation of memory :D